# How to read csv file in a rake task

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, csv, task, rake

I try to read a file named `merchant_data.csv` that is stored in `lib/tasks/merchant_data.csv` where I have this rake task in `lib/tasks/import.rake`. I get the error `No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - merchant_data.csv`. How could I read this file and go through the lines?

```rb
task advertiser: :environment do
    CSV.foreach('merchant_data.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
      ...
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to give the full path

```
csv_source = Rails.root.join("lib", "tasks", "merchant_data.csv")

CSV.foreach(csv_source, :headers => true) do |row|
  ...
end
```